# reading Cookies in C#

Tags: c#, php, cookies

i created php page with these cookies :

```
setcookie("0","hello+how+are+you",time()+30);
```

in C# i wrote that code to read cookies :

```
        string webaddr = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
        string cookiesresult = "";

        //----Establish Connection to web and get cookies [Commands]----//
        HttpWebRequest httpwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webaddr);
        httpwr.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebResponse httpwrs = (HttpWebResponse)httpwr.GetResponse();

        //----Start Getting Cookies----//
        foreach (Cookie cook in httpwrs.Cookies)
        {
            cookiesresult = cook.Value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Cookies Recieved : " + cookiesresult);
```

now cookies value should be : hello+how+are+you
but instead value is        : hello%2Bhowo%2areo%2you

so it exchanged + with o%2 and i don`t know what is the problem

Comment: It should be replacing `+` with `%2B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookies are being [URL Encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), also referred to as percent-encoding. Use the [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) method to decode them.

Comment: i am using .net framework 2 so i use system. what ? to get the HttpServerUtility ?? and thanks

Comment: It's supported in .NET framework 2.0. It's in namespace System.Web, and in System.Web.dll

Comment: i got problem with libraries , now i write a program to read cookies and some cookies are being encoded so i need to decode them and i know that i must use the library System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode to decode the cookies but whenever i type Using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode i get no library it just stop at Using System.Web; nothing more no subs of Web . i am using .net frame2 and i tried that on .net framework 4 and didn`t work . i dont use ASP i use a console application . and thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: i found HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode instead , but cant use it

Comment: @BOSS - Add `System.Web.dll` as a reference to your project. Add `using System.Web;` to the top of the class. Use the method `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` in your code to decode the cookie's value.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cookie it turns all special characters into their html equivalent.

For example a google search: http://www.google.com/?q=hello%20there%20how%20are%20you

Comment: Just to clarify: %2B in OP's example is '+' and %20 in yours is space.